# Transfer data from Sybase DB to MySQL using Spring Batch

Tags: mysql, spring, migration, sybase, spring-batch

I have to transfer all the records from Sybase to MySQL, how can I accomplish that?

This is the bean im using to connect to Sybase:

```
<bean id="SybasedataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="******" />
        <property name="username" value="*****" />
        <property name="password" value="******" />
</bean>
```

is this right?

I want to use the JDBC Cursor Item Reader to read from Sybase and then an ItemWriter to write all the data to MYSQL, there will be no processing(NOP). I am new to Spring Batch so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO.  Please note that when you are choosing tags, it will give you the explanation about what the tag means.  In this case, you chose the [batch-file] tag, which relates to DOS/Windows script files.  I have replaced  it with the [sprint-batch] tag, as that's what your question is about.

Comment: this is a easy task to accomplish with SB. read official docs, do quick tutorial and check for some examples around the net. when you have a specific problem/error came back and we will be happy to help you

Comment: @luca I followed the tutorials but I am still having problems. Can you outline what the different jobs would be? I want to use the jdbc cursor item reader.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci would you mind showing me some sample code? I've been trying for about 3 days now, and I can still figure it out.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're really asking how to connect to Sybase with Spring, correct (since that's all the configuration you've shown)?  If you're looking for more, have you gone through the Spring Batch Getting Started Guide here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Comment: @MichaelMinella I have gone through it, can you help me with an overview of how the whole transaction would look like? connect to sybase->read->write to mysql..